# 162: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "articles_pkey" when I try to run the command: psql newsdata.sql

Tags: psql

I get this when I try to connect my DB when I run the following

```
psql newsdata.sql
```

here is the whole output

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$ psql -d news -f newsdata.sql
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
psql:newsdata.sql:31: ERROR:  relation "articles" already exists
ALTER TABLE
psql:newsdata.sql:45: ERROR:  relation "articles_id_seq" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
psql:newsdata.sql:65: ERROR:  relation "authors" already exists
ALTER TABLE
psql:newsdata.sql:79: ERROR:  relation "authors_id_seq" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
psql:newsdata.sql:102: ERROR:  relation "log" already exists
ALTER TABLE
psql:newsdata.sql:116: ERROR:  relation "log_id_seq" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
psql:newsdata.sql:162: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "articles_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(23) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY articles, line 1
 setval
--------
     30
(1 row)

psql:newsdata.sql:181: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "authors_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY authors, line 1
 setval
--------
      4
(1 row)

psql:newsdata.sql:1677931: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "log_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1678923) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY log, line 1
 setval
---------
 3356657
(1 row)

psql:newsdata.sql:1677946: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "articles" are not allowed
psql:newsdata.sql:1677954: ERROR:  relation "articles_slug_key" already exists
psql:newsdata.sql:1677962: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "authors" are not allowed
psql:newsdata.sql:1677970: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "log" are not allowed
psql:newsdata.sql:1677978: ERROR:  constraint "articles_author_fkey" for relation "articles" already exists
```

I just don't understand what's dublicated key so I can fix it, I'm begginner could you provide a detailed answer for this? even if it's just a link to check, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.
The problem was because I ran this command before so now I tried `psql -d news` and it worked.
the output showed a table for relations

Answer (score 1):

DETAIL:  Key (id)=(23) already exists.
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

Script attempted to insert id=23 or id=1 but theses values are already in table.

So unique constraint violated, and each tuple have not unique id.